# Strange output when use Pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, assignment-operator, dereference

Considere the following code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x=2, y;
    int *p = &x;
    int **q = &p;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << *q << std::endl;

    *p = 8;
    *q = &y;

    std::cout << "--------------" << std::endl;

    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << *q << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of code is (of course the list numbers is not the part of output):

1. 0x7fff568e52e0
2. 0x7fff568e52e8
3. 2
4. 2
5. 0x7fff568e52e0
6. '-----------'
7. 0x7fff568e52e4
8. 0x7fff568e52e8
9. 0
10. 8
11. 0x7fff568e52e4

Except for 7 and 9, all outputs were expected for me. I appreciate someone explaining them to me.

Comment: Please don't tag C when you are asking about a C++ program. These are two distinct programming languages.

Comment: 7 is the address of `y`.  9 is due to *undefined behavior* because `y` was never initialized.

Comment: @Eljay Can you explain more? p is the pointer that is initialized by &x and does not change during code. I expected that it was the same as output 1.

Comment: `*q = &y;` is effectively the same as `p = &y;` because `*q` aliases `p` (through indirection).  Which means `p` **does** change during the code (indirectly, via `*q`).

Comment: @PeteBecker I was able to execute the code without error.

Comment: `*q = &y;` changes the value of `p`, because `q` points to `p` so `*q =... ` will change `p`.

Comment: @user17732522 -- yup. Deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `y` was not initialized

```
int x=2, y;
```

So it has an indeterminate value.

As the pointer `q` points to the pointer `p`

```
int **q = &p;
```

then dereferencing the pointer `q` you get a reference to the pointer `p`.
So this assignment statement

```
*q = &y;
```

in fact is equivalent to

```
p = &y;
```

That is after the assignment the pointer `p` contains the address of the variable `y`.

So this call

```
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

now outputs the address of the variable `y`.

7. 0x7fff568e52e4

and this call

```
std::cout << *p << std::endl;
```

outputs the indeterminate value of `y` that happily is equal to 0.

```
9. 0
```